# running migrations as a part of an MS Azure app service release pipeline for a Django web app

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-devops, kudu

I am wondering if anybody has experience with integrating a `python manage.py migrate` command into a MS Azure release pipeline. The app is being deployed using CI/CD pipeline through DevOps. In the release pipeline portion, the app is being deployed to three different stages (dev, test and prod). I have not been successful in being able to integrate the migrate command into the deployment process. I have tried achieving this by using a post deployment inline script:

```
/antenv/bin/python /home/site/wwwroot/manage.py collectstatic
/antenv/bin/python /home/site/wwwroot/manage.py migrate
```

If I run the above commands in the sandbox environment via SSH they are carried out successfully. 
However, including them in the release pipeline as a post deployment script raises the following error:

```
2020-03-22T19:00:32.8641689Z Standard error from script: 
2020-03-22T19:00:32.8727872Z ##[error]/home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: 1: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: /antenv/bin/python: not found
/home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: 2: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: /antenv/bin/python: not found

2020-03-22T19:01:34.3372528Z ##[error]Error: Unable to run the script on Kudu Service. Error: Error: Executed script returned '127' as return code. Error: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: 1: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: /antenv/bin/python: not found
/home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: 2: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1321584903618191/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: /antenv/bin/python: not found
```

I also attempted running the above in-line script as:

```
manage.py collectstatic
manage.py migrate
```

But to no avail.

Based on the [Oryx documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/master/doc/runtimes/python.md), it seems as though `manage.py collectstatic` is being run, but not `manage.py migrate`

Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we want to be able to use the release pipeline infrastructure on Azure DevOps, we cannot use `startUpCommand:  python3.6 manage.py migrate` because there is no YAML file associated with the release in devops (at least as of yet). Instead, what finally worked was:

1. Creating a script file in the project repository. I named the file `Procfile.sh`. In this file I added the following two lines of code:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

2. Add a new variable in the webapp configuration that points to that file:

```
 {
    "name": "POST_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "Procfile.sh"
  }
```

If you are running the collectstatic command in your script, you will want to disable the Oryx engine from running it as well:

```
{
    "name": "DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "true"
  },
```

See [Oryx documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/master/doc/runtimes/python.md) for more details.

Comment: This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

When using Django, you typically want to migrate the data models using `manage.py migrate` after deploying the app code. You can add `startUpCommand` with post-deployment script for this purpose:

```
startUpCommand:  python3.6 manage.py migrate
```

For details ,please refer to this [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops#considerations-for-django) document.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried what was suggested above and receive the following errors in the log output: `2020-03-24T11:46:54.0274181Z ##[error]Error: Unable to run the script on Kudu Service. Error: Error: Executed script returned '127' as return code. Error: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1401585050340838/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: 1: /home/site/VSTS_PostDeployment_1401585050340838/kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: startUpCommand:: Permission denied`

Comment: You can try to use **chmod** to give execution permissions to script as a workaround. Please refer to this [document](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Setting_up_permissions_on_a_script) and similar [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/536098/azure-devops-permission-denied-when-attempting-to.html).